# SeleniumIDE 3.12.1 - Trouble verifying text in dropdown

Tags: selenium, ide

I am new to Selenium IDE but not to QA.  I am trying to verify the values in simple dropdown but for some reason the verify text fails. 
On the page I am trying to test I have a dropdown with states that are available to select.  I am simply trying to verify that all of the states that are expected are in fact displayed.
I've recorded my steps and then added a verify text command, set the target and added my text (The text is the values in the drop down). 
I run that validation and the test fails saying actual value (Let's say X) does not match (let's say X).
As far as I can see, the text matches exactly so I am not sure what else to do. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please check first if the text added by you is same as the actual text (in terms of case-sensitivity and spacing).

Also it would be helpful if you can share the screenshot of your script or/else the script itself by exporting it.

Comment: Thank you!  I know for sure the text is identical.  I will try and get the script and upload it.

Comment: I can't attach the case here, but I have: Command: Verify text  Target: css=#insured\state|0.form-control  value: Alabama Alaska Arizona Arkansas California Colorado Connecticut Delaware District of Columbia Florida Georgia Hawaii Idaho Illinois Indiana Iowa Kansas Kentucky Louisiana Maine Maryland Massachusetts Michigan Minnesota Mississippi Missouri Montana Nebraska Nevada New Hampshire New Jersey New Mexico North Carolina North Dakota Ohio Oklahoma Oregon Pennsylvania Rhode Island South Carolina South Dakota Tennessee Texas Utah Vermont Virginia Washington West Virginia Wisconsin Wyoming